# better: switch-case or if-else in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, conditional-statements, flex4.5

i make a application which uses too much conditional statement. so every time i have two option. use **switch-case** or **if-else**, Then i interested to know that among both of them which gives me a better execution of my application. i searched a lot but they all gives me for different technology. i want to know about actionscript 3. any one wants to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: build a simple benchmark, and try it

Comment: You best try to get rid of both, if you can. Use polymorphism and keep your code readable. http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism If-statements can be unavoidable sometimes, but `switch` to me is a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt that the performance difference (if any) will be significant enough to matter, unless you're talking about some loop that you're running millions of times.

Instead I would use the one that provides greater readability - generally I find switch-case syntax to be far easier to read and maintain if you have more than 3 conditionals (if-else-else).

Answer (score 0):

Switch is definitely preferable to if/elseif/else.

It makes your code easier to read and generally performs better than if/else because if/else might have to go thru many ifs until it actually runs some code. Switch will jump straight to your code (sort of).